# if asp:Panel generate a div, what generate a span?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I'd like to know how to insert a span with an asp:Control (not in the cs, but build it in the aspx) instead of a div.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably I'm misunderstanding the question; if you want a `<span>` then why not simply use a `<span>` tag?

If you want to control it in your code behind, you can add the `runat="server"` attribute just like for any other control.

E.g.:

```
<span runat="server" ID="MySpan">Some content</span>
```

And in your code behind:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args )
{
    MySpan.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Didnt know I can use it as a user-control :) Nice!

Answer (score 6):

Typically the `asp:Label` control uses a span for specific formatting.

Comment: But only if there's no control associated to it, apparently